# Android IntentService in foreground

Tags: android, service

Hi I have got problems with launching IntentService as a foreground service. Unfortunatelly the official tutorial does not tell me much as some of methods does not exists, some are deprecated and moreover it's not said where to place the code, that they provide.

I created my own IntentService and I have overridden onCreate method. It looks following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
     Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
             .setContentTitle(getText(R.string.serviceName))
             .setContentText(getText(R.string.serviceDescription))
             .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
             .setOngoing(true)
             .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
             .build();

    startForeground(101, notification);
```

I know it's not debugging site, but surely there is something obvious, that I am missing. Settings class is my Activity class, from which startService was called, I have also set all needed things to the notification and called startForeground with nonzero first argument. Still no notification appears, although I am pretty sure, that service is working in the background.

Any help would be appreciated (btw. I have already searched for different topics on SO woth service in foreground, but with no help.)

Comment: what is your use case for having it in the foreground?

Comment: App is: you set some settings ie. Telephone number. From settings activity you press launch button, since then service starts and listens for some events and if event occurs service makes a call(useful when eg phone makes a move, but it's left home alone). I want user to be notified, that service is active. You can disable service from settings activity.

Comment: Since an IntentService is destroyed immediately after onHandleIntent() completes, you probably don't want an IntentService

Comment: Even if I will have to change it to regular service, then still I do not know how to make service run in foreground.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `Service` instead of `IntentService`, you can put the code you wrote to build the notification  & `startForeground()` in `onStartCommand` :

```
public class SettingsService extends Service {

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public SettingsService getService() {
            return SettingsService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)           {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("myService")
                .setContentText("this is an example")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(101, notification);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

Additionnaly, in `onStartCommand`, return `START_NOT_STICKY` if you dont want the service to be recreated when it is killed otherwise return `START_STICKY`